# Visual studio "cannot find the path specified" error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am having a problem creating a simple window in C++ visual studio. I started a new "empty project" and only created one `.cpp` file. When I try to run the program, I get this error:

```
Unable to start program C:\...\Project1.exe. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Why does this happen? I'm using visual studio 2010.

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>

// Function prototypes.
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam );
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow );


int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,    
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR szCmdLine,        
                    int iCmdShow )          


    #pragma region part 1 - STARTUP STUFF

    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;  
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0; 
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject( WHITE_BRUSH );   
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );            
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );        
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;          
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;           
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("Philip");  
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;    // no menu - ignore
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; // Redraw the window

    RegisterClass( &wc );  
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(
        TEXT("Philip"),         

        TEXT("window's title!"),// appears in title of window

        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    
        10, 10,                 
        200, 200,               
        NULL, NULL,             
        hInstance, NULL );      


    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow );
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    #pragma endregion

    #pragma region part 2 - ENTER A LOOP TO CONTINUALLY KEEP CHECKING WITH WIN O/S FOR USER INTERACTION

    MSG msg;

    while( GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
    {


        TranslateMessage( &msg );   

        DispatchMessage( &msg );  


    }
    #pragma endregion

    return msg.wParam;    // return from WinMain
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(   HWND hwnd,      // "handle" to the window that this message is for
                            UINT message,   // TYPE of message (e.g. WM_PAINT is a message asking to paint the window)
                            WPARAM wparam,  // information about the actual message
                            LPARAM lparam ) // MORE info about the message
{


    switch( message )
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        // upon creation, let the speaker beep at 50Hz, for 10ms.
        Beep( 50, 10 );
        return 0;
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {

            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );

            // draw a circle and a 2 squares
            Ellipse( hdc, 20, 20, 160, 160 );
            Rectangle( hdc, 50, 50, 90, 90 );
            Rectangle( hdc, 100, 50, 140, 90 );

            EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
        }
        return 0;
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage( 0 ) ;
        return 0;
        break;


    }
    return DefWindowProc( hwnd, message, wparam, lparam );
}
```

Comment: Assuming you compiled and built the application, do a search to see where it put the .exe file which is configurable.

Comment: @DavidElliman I checked and couldn't find an exe file, so i did what you said and built the project. the output was `========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: Can you run the program from the build menu?

Comment: @DavidElliman there is no run option, but i see "run code analysis on solution"

Comment: Well I usually type CTRL-F5 to build and run. Are you sure you are building and executable and not a library?

Comment: Visual studio calls it a "solution". Does this mean anything? To make it, i did `File->New->Project` then selected "empty project". I then created one source file.

Comment: Redo the same but select a "Command line Win32 Project" i.s.o "empty Pproject" it will configure your project to build an executable, copy/paste all your code in the .cpp file it create build &run

Comment: @imulsion: Did you create new .cpp file, throught Solution Explorer and add this file to "Source Files" filter (not Resource or Header)?

Comment: @user1837009 i had source files selected when i wrote the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a window then your kind of project is `Windows Form Application` (see picture above).

The solutions are an abstract concept to get together several projects. For example you could want to have a `Windows Form Application` using the features of a `Class Library`.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like VS 2010...or is that me?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel. Yep, it is.

Comment: oops, sorry, i forgot i was using a different texture pack >.< thank you, this has worked :)

Comment: hehe I'm glad to hear. Good luck!